# Java - Limit scanner input

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner, user-input

I was wondering if it was possible for Scanner to accept input only up to a certain length on a double; that is, to not allow inputs past a certain number of digits.

I know that I can use Math to get the floor to round, but I'm more interested in trying to limit the number of digits allowed after the decimal point.

For example:

> 1.00 is allowed
>
> 2.22 is allowed
>
> 10.99 is allowed
>
> 1000000000000.10 is allowed
>
> 1.999 is **not** allowed

Comment: What happens if the user types something that is "not allowed"?  How is that different from you writing code to detect the same condition?

Comment: I'm trying to see if there's a way I can do it so I don't need to write a check to make sure they're doing it the "correct" way; this is to simulate someone giving a dollar and 36 cents or something. 1.36. Not a dollar and 36.7798 cents.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases processing the number as a String helps.

```
public static boolean hasLessThanTwoDecimalDigits(double number)
{
    return String.valueOf(number).matches("\\d+\\.\\d\\d?");
}
```

Where:

- `\\d+` stands for between one and unlimited digits
- `\\.` stands for dot.
- `\\d` stands for a digit
- `\\d?` stands for zero or one digit

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine();

int integerPlaces = input.indexOf('.');
int decimalPlaces = input.length() - integerPlaces - 1;

if (decimalPlaces > 2) {
    System.out.println(input + " is not allowed");
} else {
    System.out.println(input + " is allowed");
}
```

In `integerPlaces` you get index where `.` is and then in `decimalPlaces` you get the number of decimal places after `.`

Next you simply check if `decimalPlaces` is greater than 2 and output it.

Here is [repl](https://repl.it/repls/SeashellUnusualModels) if you want to test it right away,
and the output that I got right now:

```
1.00
1.00 is allowed
2.22
2.22 is allowed
10.99
10.99 is allowed
1000000000000.10
1000000000000.10 is allowed
1.999
1.999 is not allowed
```